# how to set selected option on laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i want to set the selected option on my dropdown,
i've been set the code like this

```
@foreach($news as $news_data)
    @if($news_data->category_id)
      <option value="{{ $news_data->category_id }}" selected>{{ $news->category }}</option>
    @else
      <option value="{{ $news_data->id }}">{{ $news_data->category }}</option>
    @endif  
@endforeach
```

and this my controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    /*show current selected*/
    $news = News::find($id)
      ->leftJoin('categories','news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
      ->select('news.category_id', 'news.content', 'news.title' ,'categories.category', 'categories.id')
      ->where('news.id', '=', $id)
      ->get()->first();

      // /dd($news->id);

    return view('news.update')
    ->with('news', $news);

}
```

but i get error like this

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble posting the snippets here.

Check this out:

http://laravel.io/bin/0eYar

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi :)
thanks for your help. i'm using 2 queries here

Answer (score 0):

You're just grabbing the first data and iterating over it. What `dd($news);` gives you?

Comment: dd($news); has shown the attributes like this
`#attributes: array:5 [▼
        "category_id" => 1
        "content" => ""
        "title" => "test upload"
        "category" => "POLITIK"
        "id" => 1
      ]
`
if i didn't use the first() i get the error like this
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: You should do 2 queries here. The left join part isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

you don't select the `news.id` . But view page you fetch the `$news_data->id`

```
<option value="{{ $news_data->id }}">{{ $news_data->category }}</option>
```

Try this:

```
$news = News::leftJoin('categories','news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
      ->select('news.id','news.category_id', 'news.content', 'news.title' ,'categories.category', 'categories.id')
      ->where('news.id', '=', $id)
      ->get();
```